# Formatting XML for Twilio Response

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am attempting to receive a fax in my Laravel app, but I can't seem to format the XML properly.

Since I am just setting this up for the first time, I tried to emulate the basic how-to in the Twilio Quickstart guide.

Using the Twilio dashboard, I have set a webhook address of myapp.com/fax/sent to be notified when an incoming fax is attempting to be sent:

```
public function sent()
{
    $twimlResponse = new SimpleXMLElement("<Response></Response>");
    $recieveEl = $twimlResponse->addChild('Receive');
    $receiveEl->addAttribute('action', '/fax/received');

    return response($twimlResponse->asXML())
           ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
}
```

The error that I get from Twilio is essentially empty:

```
Error 12100 Document parse failure
```

The Twilio error request inspector shows no head or body.

I have also tried to return a hard-coded view file in place of building the xml:

view  fax.sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Receive action="/fax/received" />
</Response>
```

and then changed the sent function to:

```
public function sent()
   {
      return View::make('fax.sent')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
   }
```

This returns the same error message.

Comment: When you go to `myapp.com/fax/sent` do you get your expected XML with the correct content type?

Comment: @Andy  yes, I do

Comment: I wouldn't have thought this to matter, but try `utf-8` instead of `UTF-8` in your xml header

Comment: no luck with that either

Comment: hmmm it sounds like something is not valid with it. Could you try loading it in to an xml validator to check? This one appears to load them from URLs: http://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator

Comment: oh god...   The route was protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your twiML URL is externally accessible to Twilio (no firewall/IP restrictions, etc) and that it is valid XML with the correct Content-Type.